# Renamed files on Mac OSX and got error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:

Tags: git, macos

I have renamed a few files by changing the name to lowercase and ended up getting the following error message.

```
git checkout feature/code-quality 
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
src/assets/fonts/poppins-bold.ttf
src/assets/fonts/poppins-light.ttf
src/assets/fonts/poppins-medium.ttf
src/assets/fonts/poppins-regular.ttf
Please move or remove them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
```

Previously it was:

```
src/assets/fonts/Poppins-Bold.ttf
src/assets/fonts/Poppins-Light.ttf
src/assets/fonts/Poppins-Medium.ttf
src/assets/fonts/Poppins-Regular.ttf
```

I tried the following option which didn't work for me:
`git rm --cached`
`git reset --hard HEAD`

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the caseignore settings for git on OSX.

```
git config core.ignorecase true
```

I hope, it will make your day.